# Происхождение "вряд ли"?

Tags: этимология

Задумался о происхождении наречия "вряд ли". Скорее всего, оно происходит от "в ряд", но почему тогда употребляется для высказывания сомнения?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что маэстро behemothus совершенно прав. Скорее всего, выражение "вряд ли" - это видоизменившийся вопрос В РЯД ЛИ? (Ср. В ряд ли с прочим это ставится? Можно ли поставить это в тот же ряд?) Частица ЛИ вопросительная, она и помогает выразить сомнение, что некий предмет или некое явление, действие можно поставить в один ряд с чем-то. Этот предмет, явление, действие может быть похожим на предыдущие, но  по каким-то причинам кажется выбивающимся из этого ряда.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно, от "в ряд". А что удивительного, что сомнения? Сомнения-то от "ли", а у "ряда" тут тот же смысл что и, например, в "из ряда вон выходящий". "Вряд ли" - сомнительно, что случай в этот ряд попадает.